# Where to find MatofByte library in OpenCV , using in java

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am trying to find the library for openCV.

```
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;  
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
```

I found just by importing javaCV,  am not getting the above API.
I need to download some other libraries as well.
I am very new to openCV , so can any tell me how to get these libraries for importing in Java

I did follow the link of jar , only change I did is I found a jar inside openCV extracted directory C:\Opencv\opencv\build\java, So I just imported that jar as library , it didn;t work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported those core libraries into the build path?

Check http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html and

> http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html ,in case you are using visual studio.

Comment: I did , but then I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java246 in java.library.path.. I found a jar inside C:\Opencv\opencv\build\java , dont understand just by adding as library . is not working. why

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708150/intellij-does-not-find-native-libraries-for-opencv-when-adding-jar-as-a-dependen) out

Answer (score 0):

Those classes are only available in OpenCV for Java (http://opencv.org), which is a totally different wrapper than JavaCV (https://code.google.com/p/javacv/).

You need to use the classes corresponding to the libraries you are linking.