# How do you link a native library to a jar in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get OpenCV set up in IntelliJ, however I'm stuck on figuring out how tell IntelliJ where to find the native library location.

In Eclipse, after adding a jar, you can set the location of the Native library in the Build Config screen.

e.g.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in IntelliJ IDE?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure you need it as a dependency, you just need to add the option to the VM invocation so the library is found at run-time.

At least in the first sample I have looked at (samples/java/ant/SimpleSample) the native library is loaded at runtime with these lines:

[image: SimpleSample code screencapture]

So, the library is not a compiM to find the native library at run-time, specify the java.library.path to point to the directory where the library can be found, using the -D VM option - in your IntelliJ run configuration.

[image: Run Configuration for JAR Application specifying where to find native library]

NOTE: If on Mac OS X you need to create a copy/link of the .so shared library built to one with the same name, but the .dynlib extension

Answer (score 6):

Once the library is added, you can set the Native Library Location as follows:

1. Make sure the library is selected (highlighted). In my case, there only is one Library called lwjgl.
2. On the right panel, select the little + Symbol (below "Name" and above "Classes")
3. Select the directory you want to specify as Native Library Location and confirm
4. Select Native Library Location in the next dialog.

[image: Screenshot of Category Selection Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

File-->Project Structure-->Modules-->Select Dependencies Tab-->Select Module Source-->at the right corner green '+' button-->Library-->new Library-->java-->select External jar file-->OK-->add Selected

or

Without selecting library from + button directly select jar dependencies

here are some screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you're explaining how to add external jars...he's wanting to know how to associate .dll files or .so files.

Comment: However, it helped me, thanks a lot. Still not upvoting, as it might be wrong answer to the question, which i did not read lol

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148086/222867

Windows uses the PATH variable instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH to load DLL's. I set the PATH environment variable appropriately and then restart Idea. 
This however, may not be the most convenient option